# Python dataframe restricted values

Tags: python, dataframe, types

Possibly a beginner's question:
I have a very large dataset, stored in a CSV file. In column 1 of this dataset there are only four potential values ('a', 'b', 'c', nan).
I am loading this dataset via 
    pandas.read_csv
In order to save memory, can I declare a special type for this column?  This type should only allow for these four values, such that each entry only takes 3 bits.  I'd like to keep 'a', 'b', 'c', and nan appearing when looking at the corresponding column.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3, you could use the built-in **Enum** class, which is documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html.

As for only using 3 bits, I'll be honest and say that kind of strictness with memory is unusual to worry about when using Python. However, you might could look into using Pypi's "bitarray" found here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/0.8.1

Comment: Many thanks! Indeed, also the category class seems to do the job.